# seeking possible memory leak with C#/C++ wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have a C# program that calls a C++ DLL.  The wrapper code for the function is question is shown below.

As this function is called repeatedly, memory use continues to grow and it *appears* as if there's a memory leak.  And it appears that the issue is associated with the `matchingFragments->Add` line in the code below.  If I comment out that line, memory use is stable.

In previous iterations of this program, where `matchingFragments` wasn't a list but was set to a fixed number of elements, memory use would be stable throughout repeated calls to this function.  So I suspect some memory isn't being freed somewhere, but I don't know what the issue is, whether it's `matchedFragments`, `returnedFragments`, or neither.  Nor do I know any of this well enough (I'm a C developer struggling with this) to know how to debug this, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
bool SearchWrapper::SpectrumSearch([Out] List<FragmentWrapper^>^% returnedFragments)
{
   vector<Fragment> matchedFragments;

   // perform the search
    bool isSuccess = _pSearchMgr->PeptideSearch(matchedFragments);

   // Convert data back to the managed world

   returnedFragments = gcnew List<FragmentWrapper^>();
   for (auto frag : matchedFragments)
   {
      returnedFragments->Add(gcnew FragmentWrapper(frag));
   }

   return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: if you have a C++ DLL it may use dynamic memory allocation. just think of it like a C DLL. if the DLL has a function which allocates memory, then it probably also has a function to free that memory somehow, since C and C++ are not garbage collected languages. In C#, while you do have garbage collection, it is only for .NET managed objects. when you call a DLL which allocates memory, that is your responsibility to free later. so if the DLL does not provide a way to free the memory... you're out of luck pretty much.

Comment: Chris, thank you for the reply.  I guess I am aware that any memory allocated in the C++ DLL needs to be freed.  So I should've been a bit more specific with what I was seeking help on.  Here's a couple of  follow-up questions that might help me.  1) In my code example above, in the line "returnedFragments->Add(gcnew FragmentWrapper(frag));", does the "gcnew" directive imply that the returned data/memory will be garbage collected?

Comment: Question 2): at the very head of this SearchWrapper::SpectrumSearch() function, how do I clear any memory that "returnedFragments" currently holds?  Since that variable is what holds allocated memory being returned to C#, it's being passed back to this function in subsequent calls so I should be able to free any memory it holds at the head of this function (assuming that memory isn't automatically garbage collected).  I just can't figure out the correct syntax to do so.  And it has to be this variable/memory because if I comment out that line, I have no memory issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the actual fix to my issue was the need for a finalizer for the FragmentWrapper class.  There was a destructor but not a finalizer.  Once I added the finalizer, the memory leak went away.